# Netlify CMS and NextJS: Do I NEED to use Netlify to deploy, or can I use Vercel?

Tags: next.js, netlify, vercel, netlify-cms

Right now I am hosting my NextJS application using Vercel, and am attempting to add a blog via Netlify CMS. It seems like all the documentation I find online points to having to use Netlify. Is there any reason not to use Netlify instead of Vercel?

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of using Netlify CMS, regardless of the frontend you are using, it would be smoother process to deploy it to Netlify, compared to Vercel. I've heard some people had some issues and encountered more steps todo deploying such app to Vercel.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I've really enjoyed Vercel so far. I'm sure the experience is similar on Netlify. I ended up making an MDX blog for my site instead of using Netlify CMS

Comment: @drewkiimon I totally feel you - using vercel was (and still is) a great experience for me as well. Funny enough, I switched my personal site to MDX blog with vercel too!

Comment: Good choice my friend! Especially if it's just you or other coders writing posts, it's perfect to use MDX. If you want to see my code let me know! Or you can look at my personal website (I think it's on my profile).

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, saw your site and I very like it! (Also saw your github repository for your site: https://github.com/drewkiimon/andrewpagan.com :) I see that you've recently started a new venture - wish you best of luck!

Comment: thank you so much! Very excited to have started my new adventure. :) Have a good one!